# How do I account for spatial autocorrelation in my zero inflated negative binomial model?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, spatial-correlation

I am building a zero-inflated NB model, and I know my data are spatially autocorrelated (as per the acf test).

My current model is:

```
ZINB_NAFO <- zeroinfl(num_incidents_NAFO ~ log(vessel_hours_NAFO) + num_whales_NAFO + offset(log(area_NAFO)) + factor(Season), dist = 'negbin', data = df_NAFO_Seasons)
```

Is there a term I can throw into the model to account for this? If not, could one provide step by step instructions on how to account for this in my model? Thank you!

Comment: And how did you conduct an `acf` test accounting for the zero-inflated negative binomial structure of the data, adjusting for season, and offsets, among other things?

Comment: Using the acf(resid(ZINB_NAFO)) command.

Comment: You say you did a test? `acf` does not conduct any test of autocorrelation. Output could help. Also how are these data sorted so that you are certain that the `acf` function is presenting spatial autocorrelation?